# Generador de numero random C++

Tags: c++, array

el problema es el siguiente tengo mi codigo en el cual se genera 10 numeros al azar en un arreglo, luego los muestra y luego los ordena, lo que quiero es que al volver a ejecutar la funcion de "llenar" que es la que genera los numeros se genere un arreglo con nuevos numeros y no sean los mismos de la vez anterior.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;
int llenar();
int mostrar();
int array[10];
int burbuja();
int main(){
 llenar();
 mostrar();
 burbuja();
 llenar();
 mostrar();
};

int burbuja(){
  int i,j,aux;

  for(i=0;i<10;i++){
      for(j=0;j<10;j++){
          if(array[j] > array[j+1]){
              aux = array[j];
              array[j] = array[j+1];
              array[j+1] = aux;
          }
      }
  }

  for(i=1;i<11;i++){
      cout<<array[i]<<" ";
  }
  cout<<endl;
}

int mostrar(){
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        cout << array[i] << " ";
   }
cout<<endl;
};

int llenar(){
  array[0]='NULL';

  int num, c;
  srand(time_t());

  for(c = 1; c <= 10; c++)
  {
      array[c-1] = 1 + rand() % (100 - 1);
     /* cout << array[c-1]<< " ";*/
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tinenes unos cuantos *fallitos*:

```
int llenar( ) {
  array[0]='NULL';
```

Si es `int array[10]`, seguramente lo que quieres hacer es

```
array[0] = 0;
```

Cambiando lo anterior, y también `srand( time( NULL ) );`, los números ya empiezan a salir aleatorios.

Aparte de eso, declaras

```
int burbuja()
```

y

```
int mostrar( )
```

Sin embargo, en ninguna de ellas devuelves **nada**, y el compilador te avisa.

Y el último:

```
int llenar( ) {
  array[0] = 0;

  int num, c;
```

Tienes otro aviso de que no usas la variable `num`.

#### Edito

Te repite los números porque, entre sucesivas llamadas a `srand( time( NULL ) )`, **pasa demasiado poco tiempo**.

Para que se note mas el efecto, quita `srand( )` de la función `llenar( )` y ponlo **al principio de `main( )`**

```
int main( ) {
  srand( time( NULL ) );
  ... resto del código ...
```

Comment: El problema no es que me los genere, sino que al volver a llamar la funcion son los mismos numeros, y en burbuja y mostrar no retorno nada simplemente imprimo el arreglo no se si este mal pero hasta ahorita me funciono asi, y lo de num tienes razon ya lo borre

Comment: @RicardoJesusJarquinPerez Editado. Pruebalo ahora :-)

Comment: Tienes razon el problema era mio al llamar la funcion, ya terminado el programa con un menu(switch) donde pongo 3 tipos de ordemanietos y las opciones de mostrar y llenar ya no se repiten muchas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres "*Generador de numero random C++*" olvida por completo las utilidades de C como [`rand`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/rand) y las cabeceras de C [`<stdlib.h>` y `<time.h>`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/c/header).

---

A partir del estándar C++11 el lenguaje C++ ofrece una completa librería de [generación de números pseudoaleatorios](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) que permite escoger la [distribución de probabilidad](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribuci%C3%B3n_de_probabilidad) (uniforme, Bernoulli, Poisson, normal, discreta, constante, lineal...), el tipo subyacente del valor generado e incluso el algoritmo a usar (minstd, mt19937, ranlux, knuth...).

De tu pregunta deduzco que quieres una [distribución uniforme](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribuci%C3%B3n_uniforme_discreta) (que es lo que ofrece `rand()`<sup>1</sup>) entre 1 y 100. Con la librería de números pseudoaleatorios de C++ puede hacerse así:

```
// Este arreglo tiene todos los valores a 0 por defecto. El compilador se encarga de ello.
int array[10]{};

//vv <---- devuelve void, no int.
void llenar(){
    // El random device gestiona las semillas de generacion
    std::random_device rd;
    // Usamos el algoritmo mt19937
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    // Obtendremos una distribucion uniforme entre 1 y 100
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(1, 100);

    for (auto &valor : array){
        valor = dis(gen);
    }

    // La funcion no devuelve nada porque no tiene nada que devolver.
}
```

Cada vez que se llame `llenar` se creará un nuevo [`std::random_device`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device) el cuál tendrá una semilla diferente y en consecuencia dará números distintos.

---

<sup>1</sup>Pero su uniformidad se ve destruida al utilizar la operación de módulo, como sucede en tu código.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a incluir la librería *ctime*:

```
#include <ctime>
```

Y luego en la función *llenar*, cambia:

```
srand(time_t());
```

Por:

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

La función *srand* define una semilla que cambia la secuencia pseudoaleatoria que genera *rand*. Usando *time(NULL)* se emplea como semilla el valor actual de tiempo, que hará que cada vez que se ejecute el programa la secuencia que genera *rand* sea diferente. Tu código ya está haciendo esto, pero (sin probarlo), creo que de esta forma debería funcionar.

Comment: Lo intente como lo mencionas pero no funciona, incluso cada que trato de compilarlo nuevamente se queda con los mismos de la vez anterior, osea ya no los cambia lo volvi a compilar 5 veces y siempre me dio el mismo